# Zigbee Relay board communication with Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, xbee

I have bought this [wireless ZigBee relay board](http://www.controlanything.com/Merchant2/merchant.mvc?Screen=PROD&Store_Code=NCD&Product_Code=ZADR410PROXR_ZBMESH&Category_Code=).

I was wandering about an arduino sketch to get started, I have searched for 2 days now but with no results.

What I was thinking of is to have an Arduino with ZigBee module to send signal to another ZigBee device on top of the relay, to be able to open/close relay.

So, **can anyone share a sample sketch for that board?**

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this library : https://code.google.com/p/xbee-arduino/

This is the XBee Library for Arduino, you will find simple sketch that are perfect bases for the application you're trying to do.